# Awkward roots of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let there be a polynomial function, with integer coefficients, of least degree such that $7^\frac{1}3 + 49^\frac13$ is a root of the polynomial. What is  the product of the roots of the $f(x) = 0$?

In problems which state the degree of the polynomial as least degree (with additional relevant information), is it assumed that we have to take the polynomial as degree 3 or 2? 
Considering how tedious the cubic polynomial solution is, I don't think that is to be used almost anywhere.
How is one supposed to go about such a problem?

Comment: Are you aware of Vieta's formulas?

Comment: Yes I am @Cataline

Comment: Try cubing the expression, and see what the result is. The minimum polynomial becomes clear after you have cubed it, i you are observant enough.

Comment: Ah damn, should have seen that. Thanks!

Comment: However, you have not fully solved the problem yet. You must show that your resulting polynomial is in fact the minimum polynomial. Eisenstein's Criterion should help you out (the explanation on Wikipedia is pretty straightforward if you don't know what it is).

Comment: The least degree polynomial is $x-7^\frac{1}3 -49^\frac13$.

Comment: So Sat D should fix the problem.  Perhaps add that the polynomial should have integer coefficients.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\alpha=7^{\frac13}$ so $\alpha^3=7$. We need to calculate the minimal polynomial of $x=\alpha+\alpha^2$. One has $x^3=\alpha^3+3\alpha^2\alpha^2+3\alpha\alpha^4+\alpha^6=7+3\cdot7\alpha+3\cdot7\alpha^2+49=56+21x$

Thus the searched minimal polynomial is $p(x)=x^3-21x-56$